# ngx-translate for a large app

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate with a large angular app.Currently we have 18 modules and our estimate is we will be having nearly 40 modules until production.
I am keeping my translations in single json file for each language i.e en.json, fr.json.
I am unable to figure out how to handle my single en.json file.

Note: We don't want to use module wise translation as it will get too tricky for us to send so many different json files to a translation agency.

What can be the neatest way to handle translation in a single file ?
Apart from creating regions, is there any other solution?

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
  {
"WELCOME": "Welcome",
"LANGUAGE": "Language",
"LANGUAGE_EN": "english",
"LANGUAGE_ES": "spanish",
"LANGUAGE_PT": "portugese",
"LANGUAGE_RU": "russian",
"LANGUAGE_ZH_HANS": "chinese",
"TITLE_MONITORING": "Monitor",
"TITLE_MAP": "Map",
"TITLE_REPORTING": "Reports",
"TITLE_RULES": "Rules",
"TITLE_SCRIPTS": "Scripts",
"UNASSIGNED_DEVICES": "Unassigned devices"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the following ways and I prefer option 1 + A. But for example [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) uses option 2 + B. It really depends on your preferences...

[image]

```
1) Single JSON file for each language
assets/i18n/en.json
assets/i18n/cs.json

2) Multiple JSON files for each language
assets/i18n/en/moduleA.json
assets/i18n/en/moduleB.json
assets/i18n/cs/moduleA.json
assets/i18n/cs/moduleB.json

A)  Without regions
{
    "moduleA.componentA.title": "ComponentA title",
    "moduleB.componentB.title": "ComponentB title"
}

B) With regions
{
    "moduleA": {
        "componentA": {
            "title": "ComponentA title"
        }
    },
    "moduleB": {
        "componentB": {
            "title": "ComponentB title"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: going wiht 1+B ;)